# How convert csv file to dataset?

Tags: python, csv, image-processing, dataset

I have a CSV file that contains two columns:
First column: name of the image.
Second column: a label for the image
I try to build a supervised classification model for images by python but I need to convert CSV file to dataset. could any help how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you maybe mean that you want to convert it to a `pandas` dataframe? For that use `pandas.read_csv()`.

Comment: thank you BoarGules, I always see examples from Kearas and Kaggle that asking to download datasets for the training model, I do not know what datasets contain? is dataframe the same as the datasets they mentioned?

Comment: *Dataset* is a very general term. It might mean a file, or a bunch of files, or zipfile containing a `sqlite` database, or any number of other things. But if you want to convert something *to* a dataset, one has to know what kind of dataset. Your `.csv` file is a dataset already. What are you planning to do with it, that it needs converting?

Comment: Thank you BoarGules again for explaining the terms , I have now clear vision .